# How dependencies works on gnu Makefile?

Tags: makefile, patch

How dependencies works on gnu Makefile ?

I want to create a Makefile which:
- will apply some patches (in our exmaple, apply main.patch on main.c)
- create a programm called toto from patched main.c file

```
my_patch=./main.patch
all: toto

patch: $(my_patch)
    echo "apply patch"

main.o: main.c
    gcc -o main.o -c main.c -Wall

toto: patch main.o $(my_patch)
    echo "build"
    gcc -o toto main.o
```

but, the patch are always applied ... which leads me on my question:
"How dependencies works on gnu Makefile ?"

How can I tell to gnu make that it's useless to apply main.patch if the date of main.patch is smaller than the binary toto

thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phony target (`patch`) is confusing things. The `patch` rule modifies `main.c`, so let that be the target:

```
my_patch=./main.patch
all: toto

main.c: $(my_patch)
    echo "apply patch"

main.o: main.c
    gcc -o main.o -c main.c -Wall

toto: main.o # no need to specify $(my_patch) here
    echo "build"
    gcc -o toto main.o
```

**P.S.** while you're at it, you may as well introduce [automatic variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables); the makefile is cleaner and easier to maintain that way:

```
main.o: main.c
    gcc -o $@ -c $< -Wall

toto: main.o # no need to specify $(my_patch) here
    echo "build"
    gcc -o $@ $^
```